# How to refresh recyclerView after changing data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on developing an application that contains (recyclerView ) display member responses.I have a problem after a member posts a new comment the (recyclerView ) is not updated in real time.
How can I update the data (recyclerView ) after entering new data without the user exiting or closing the application؟

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<List_Data>list_data;

    public MyAdapter(List<List_Data> list_data) {
        this.list_data = list_data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_data,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        List_Data listData=list_data.get(position);
        holder.txtname.setText(listData.gettext());
        holder.txtmovie.setText(listData.getmovie_id());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list_data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView txtname,txtmovie,ImageView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtname=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            txtmovie=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_moviename);
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class StatusFragment extends Fragment {


    Button btn_send_comment;
    EditText ETXT_comment;
String id;
    private List<List_Data> list;
    private RecyclerView rvy;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    ImageView  btn_add_comments;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.status, container, false);
        ETXT_comment = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ETXT_comment);
        btn_add_comments = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_comments);
        btn_send_comment = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_send_comment);
        Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();
        final String movie_id = i.getStringExtra("id");
        rvy=(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        rvy.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvy.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        list=new ArrayList<>();
        adapter=new MyAdapter(list);
        getComment(movie_id);

//----------------Send Commant
        btn_send_comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String comment_text = ETXT_comment.getText().toString().trim();
                if (comment_text.equals("")) {
                } else {
                   //
                    final String REGISTER_URL = "http://0000000/Comment.php";
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                               //  getComment(movie_id);
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("id", id);
                            params.put("comment", comment_text);

                            return params;
                        }
                    };
                    RequestQueue requestQueue = (RequestQueue) Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                }
            }





        });
//--------------------
        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

private void getComment(String id){
    final String HI ="http://0000000/Cm.php?id=" + id ;
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, HI, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("info");

                for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++ ){
                    JSONObject ob=array.getJSONObject(i);
                    List_Data listD=new List_Data(ob.getString("comment")
                            ,ob.getString("name"));
                    list.add(listD);
                  //  adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, list_data.size());
                   // rv.removeAllViews();

                }
                rvy.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


}

}
```

Also whene I put getComment(movie_id); into onResponse it's work but there are other problem it's show data Repeats in two times For each comment from user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Move `rvy.setAdapter(adapter)` from `getComment()` to  `onViewCreated()`
- Clear the list at the start of your `getComment()` method, add this line:

  **list.clear()**

In your code, you appended the same items to this instance of List when you call .add(), hence, repeated elements appear.

- After list.add(listD), call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add new comment into your list and then call the statement

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Where  I can set it exactly because I tried this line in different locations and it didn't work with me

Comment: Have you tried in onResponse() function? That's the only suitable place i think.

'list.add(comment_text)' and then refresh adapter

Comment: Try to set adapter right after you created it and refresh it in getComment() function. After you exit and go back again RecyclerView shows new records?

Comment: whene I put getComment(movie_id); into onResponse it's work but there are other problem it's show data Repeats in two times For each comment from user

Comment: Check how your list looks like before and after adding new user. Make sure you are not calling getComment more than 1 time. Should be used once at the start only.

Comment: I use it at the beginning of activity only so that the user can see the comments he got from other members and after posting the new comment, use it in the Send New Comment button as well

Comment: Mostly try to ignore `notifyDataSetChanged()`, this kills performance. Checkout for more detailed `notifyItemInserted()` method.

Answer (score 0):

When you return a new comment, you didn't add the `RecyclerView` adapter list with the new comment. What you just did is updating the fragment list with the new comment, and the adapter has no idea about this list update.

So, modify you adapter to accept a new comment method and update the list with just the new inserted row using `notifyItemInserted()`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<List_Data>list_data;

    public MyAdapter(List<List_Data> list_data) {
        this.list_data = list_data;
    }

    public addComment(List_Data comment) {
        this.list_data.add(comment);
        notifyItemInserted(list_data.size() - 1); // Updating adapter list
    }

    // ...  rest of code
}
```

And in your `getComment()` use the new added adapter method when you get the response.
Notice the change in `// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Updating adapter list`

```
private void getComment(String id){
    final String HI ="http://0000000/Cm.php?id=" + id ;
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, HI, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("info");

                for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++ ){
                    JSONObject ob=array.getJSONObject(i);
                    List_Data listD = new List_Data(ob.getString("comment")
                            ,ob.getString("name"));
                    list.add(listD);
                    adapter.addComment(listD); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Updating adapter list

                   // rv.removeAllViews();

                }
                rvy.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


}
```

finally don't forget to uncomment the usage of the `getComment()` within the `btn_send_comment` button listener.